# PHP add query to variable inside foreach loop (WP)

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create an array for each URL variable. For each instance of this variable `Extras`, I need to create an array, which is later used as a meta_query for my WP query.

Right now, I have the following code, but it is not adding the array correctly to the meta_query..

```
$extras = $_GET["extras"];

if(!empty($extras)) {
    foreach ($extras as $extra) {
        $args14 .= array('key' => 'extras', 'value' => $extra, 'compare' => 'LIKE' );
    }   
} 

$loop = new WP_Query(array( 
                        'meta_query' => array(
                            'relation' => 'AND',
                            $args3,$args4,$args5,$args6,$args7,$args8,$args9,$args10,$args11,$args12,$args13,$args14
                        ),
                    ) 
                );
```

The other arguments work fine and are correctly added to the meta_query, but I am having trouble with the foreach loop..

Anyone who can point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you you have a typo, missing  a quotation mark after $_GET["{extras..

Comment: Yes, just a typo here. I added this for clarification where the $extras variable comes from.

Comment: Can you add an example of what is returned when you `print_r()` any one of the other `$args` like `$args3`.

Comment: Please do a `var_dump($_GET['extras']);` and show us what it said.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

It may need updates depending:

- the exact format of the `$_GET["extras"];` content format (`explode()`, separator used)
- the format of the data contained in post meta with `extras` key (int, word, serialized data)

```php
$extras = $_GET[ 'extras' ];

//if $extras already an PHP array of string: good, else you may need to explode() it to get an PHP array from the string

$query_params = [
    //other wp_query param may be needed to secure the query to public/wanted content
    //if no $_GET[ 'extras' ];, array will be empty for wp query!
];

if ( ! empty( $extras ) ) {
    $query_params['meta_query'] = [
        //we us "OR", as its "post with extra 1, or post with extra 2", AND would mean "post with extra 1 AND extra 2", but a post can only have a single value of a given meta key
        //if "extras" meta_key contain a serialized value, like will match any post with the meta containing at least one of the extras values
        'relation' => 'OR',
    ];
    foreach ( $extras as $extra ) {
        $query_params['meta_query'][] = [
            'key'     => 'extras',
            'value'   => $extra,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ];
    }
}

$loop = new WP_Query( $query_params );
```